# upload files with same name to aws s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Below is an example for my scenario,

1) User uploads file named 'sample-file.pdf' from UI with presigned url.
2) User again uploads file with same name 'sample-file.pdf'
3) I want both files to stay on the same location with newly uploaded file name appended as (1). So for example, the newly uploaded file name will be 'sample-file(1).pdf'.
4) If the user uploads same file name again, just number will be incremented and all files will be at same location/folder in s3 bucket.

Is there any easy and quick solution to this problem.

Thanks,
Yogesh

Answer (score 0):

```
.
├── test1.txt
├── test2.txt
├── test3.txt
└── test4.txt

$ for i in $(ls); do echo $1 && aws s3 cp ./$i s3://your_s3bucket_name/$i; done
```

so you can use a small bash script loop to do it...

So if you have whitespaces in your filename. You can try this instead:

```
#!/bin/sh

find .  -type file -name "*" -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do
  #  echo $file
    KEY=$(basename "$file")
    echo $KEY
    echo aws s3api put-object --bucket iamtestingiamtesting --key '"'$KEY'"' --body $file
    aws s3api put-object --bucket iamtestingiamtesting --key '"'$KEY'"' --body $file
done
```

Also normally this easiest way is to use `aws s3 sycn`

```
aws s3 sync ./local_dir s3://your_s3_bucket --delete //  Files that exist in the destination but not in the source are deleted during sync.
```

or you can use `aws s3 cp`

```
aws s3 cp ./local_dir  s3://your_s3_bucket --recursive
```

Comment: There are a few problems with this proposed solution. It would not handle filenames with whitespace, it doesn't solve the problem of appending a version number, and it doesn't make use of pre-signed URLs (which are an important component of this question).

Comment: @jarmod - Thanks for the comments. I have just updated the scripts. And once your bucket has version enabled. you don't really need to have the version in your file name since everytime you upload something you will have etag attached to your file.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is create an S3 Event on Object Create that sends the event to a lambda.  The logic of the lambda would.

```
if object name doesn't not contain (#)
then
   copy name.ext to name(#).ext
end if
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no simple, out of the box solution that I'm aware of.

The biggest challenge you have here is that you are using pre-signed URLs. When you use a pre-signed URL, the user of the pre-signed URL cannot dictate the filename in S3; instead, the creator of the pre-signed URL dictates it in advance.

So, one way to solve this is that the generator of the pre-signed URL (I'm assuming that's done programmatically through awscli scripting or similar) should first check for the presence of an existing object with the desired key (and any versioned variants) then return a pre-signed URL for the object with the next free version number, as needed. If the object does not yet exist, then just return a regular pre-signed URL without the version number. This is not ideal, especially if multiple clients are calling the script concurrently, but it could work in a simple scenario.